# Cannot access the localhost of the guest OS in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, localhost

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 OS as my host OS and CentOS 6.6 (Minimal) as my guest OS running on VirtualBox.

> > I can SSH the guest OS from my Ubuntu terminal, but I can't access the localhost of CentOS via the browser in Ubuntu.
> >     I have installed nginx as my local server.
> >     I am using a bridged adapter (using eth0).

Comment: *localhost* of host/guest is not a *localhost* for guest/host acc. To access anything in the guest from the host you have to use guest IP *(and guest IP is differ of host IP — they does, right?)*

Answer (score 0):

You can access the guest by typing in the IP address of the guest in a browser. To find the IP address, you can ssh into the guest OS and run `ip a | grep net` if it is a bridged adapter the IP address will likely start with 192.168.*.*

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I forgot to start nginx.

Comment: You are very welcome! That happens to the best of us. :)